# Save function outputs (including pandas DataFrame) to workspace in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, save, output

Created a function in Python with filepath string as input. Function returns a list and a dataframe. How to call the function properly in order to save the dataframe to workspace?
Code works perfectly without the function but I need the output for further caluclations.
I want to save the whole dataframe, not just parts of it. Haven't found any online solution, it's just too plain simple I guess. Thanks in advance!

**FUNCTION:**

```
def import_r_data(filepath):

    r('load("{}")'.format(filepath))
    tmp_obj = r['tmp.obj']
    data = build_py_from_ro(tmp_obj)
    dataframe = data['test1']['test2']

    column_list = list(dataframe)
    return column_list
    return dataframe
```

**CALL FUNCTION:** (error occurs here, dataframe output (left side) is set incorrectly)

```
column_list, dataframe = import_r_data('filepathstring')
```

**ERROR:**

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION (thanks to ayhan and DeepSpace):**

```
return column_list, dataframe
```

Comment: The line below return column_list will not be executed. If you want to return a tuple, try `return column_list, dataframe` I don't think this is the actual problem with your code, so I am not posting this as an answer.

Comment: Solved it for me, thank you! :) Overlooked the wrong return statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return column_list
return dataframe
```

Once you hit the first return statement the function returns, and the the second return statement is never reached. That's why the line `column_list, dataframe = import_r_data('filepathstring')` raises a `ValueError`:

`import_r_data` returns a single object but you try to assign that single value to a tuple.

You should change these 2 lines to `return column_list, dataframe`

Comment: Okay, searched on the wrong side, this fixes it! Wow, thank you so much, wasted a whole hour searching for the solution! And thanks to "ayhan", too. :)